# How do I pass on my build file from Jenkins to Saltstack master

Tags: jenkins, build, puppet, salt-stack, configuration-management

We have a Jenkins system to automate build from Github, now we are implementing a Saltstack system. So I need to integrate my Jenkins with Salt-master so that it passes all the new builds to the master which then sends it across the salt-clients(minions).

The saltstack setup is in AWS cloud and and the Jenkins machine is outside the cloud in a local setup.

Answer (score 0):

You could enable the salt-api and using the following plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/saltstack-plugin then all of your jenkins builds can execute states / orchestrations etc. to any minions on a per job basis.

Another way of doing this is to have a minion running on the salt-master and install the jenkins slave on the same box. Then restrict the jenkins jobs to that jenkins slave and execute the commands as if you were at the command line. NOTE: this option requires a bit more configuration.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is about how to get artifacts from Jenkins to SaltStack.